# I was tasked with creating a function that swaps adjacent letters of a word and returns the list of the candidate words.

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

An example of this would be the word "walk" which would produce a candidate set of ['awlk', 'wlak', 'wakl'].

This is what I have currently:

```
def main():
    word = "jack"
    wordL = len(word)
    listS = []

    for i in range((wordL)-1):
        current = word[i+1]
        word[i+1] = word[i]
        word[i] = current
        listS.append(word)
    print (listS)
main()
```

I am using the word "jack" as a test which should produce a set of candidate words. However, this doesn't seem to be working. I am new to python and would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since strings are immutable, you cannot change characters in a string object. To achieve what you want, you can change string into a list, do whatever you desire on the list and then convert the list back to string.

```
word = list("jack") # String is converted to list
wordL = len(word)
listS = []

for i in range((wordL)-1):
    current = word[i+1]
    word[i+1] = word[i]
    word[i] = current
    listS.append("".join(word)) # list is converted to string and appended.
print (listS)
```

Output :

`['ajck', 'acjk', 'ackj']`

Comment: Thank you so much!